# jQuery 1.5 Memory leak in IE8

Tags: jquery, memory, internet-explorer-8, memory-leaks

I believe I may have found a fairly simple leak in the latest release of jQuery.

```
var  listen = function(){};
var testLeak = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i<100; i++){
        var item = {};
        item.elem = $(document.createElement('div'));
        item.addListener = function(name,listener){
            var self = this;
            var wrappedListener = function(){
                return listener.apply(self,arguments);
            }
            this.elem.bind(name, wrappedListener);
            wrappedListener = null;
        }
        item.addListener('eventName',listen );
        item.elem.unbind();
        item.elem.remove();  //with this un-commented, the loop leaks
        // item.elem = null; //with this also un-commented, the leak dissapears
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(testLeak, 100);
}
```

I have created a project on jsfiddle that demonstrates this:

http://jsfiddle.net/rJ8x5/8/

It is important to note that if I *do not* call .remove(), this does not leak, and if I do call .remove() but set the .elem reference to null, it also does not leak. It is as though jQuery is holding a reference to item when I call .remove() which, in-turn, holds a reference to .elem.
Any thoughts?
As you can see, I have set the wrappedListener to null in an attempt to prevent any inadvertent closures, but this does not help.

EDIT: I updated the jsfiddle script to actually add the node to the DOM. This does *not* affect behavior

EDIT2: So a solution to the problem has been found, but it is still not clear to me why this script will leak only when you include the call to remove(). Still hoping for an answer...

Comment: I'm guessing this is it here http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8171?cversion=1&cnum_hist=6

Comment: TL;DR - in IE, .unbind() eventually calls detachevent. Turns out, if a closure-based memory leak is made (as it is in my example with "var item = {};"), detachevent will _not_ signal that the javascript/DOM circular reference has been broken. You HAVE to null the reference to the element manually. Why the call to remove() seems to get things into this state was never determined...
If anyone can explain this, I would appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, if a closure-based memory leak is made (as it is in my example with "var item = {};"), detachevent will not signal that the javascript/DOM circular reference has been broken. You HAVE to null the reference to the element manually. Why the call to remove() seems to get things into this state was never determined