# memory leak in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, signalr

I seem to have a memory leak in IE9. It works just fine in Chrome. The memory leak is on the client machine. I left this page open for days in chrome and no leak.

Using jquery 1.9.0, signalr rc2

This page uses signalr and refreshes it's contents every 5 seconds with what comes from the server.

I have four tabs/divs that do this.

```
proxy.on('newRequests', function (data, updatetime) {
    newrequestupdatetime.text('Last updated: ' + updatetime);
    numberofnewrequests.text('Number of cases found: ' + data.length);
    numberofnewrequeststab.text('(' + data.length + ')');
    var h = '';
    $.each(data, function (i, val) { h += '<li><a href="/requests/' + val.Ref + '">' + val.Ref + '</a> ' + val.Type + '</li>'; });
    newrequests.html(h);
});
```

newrequests is an ul on the page which I initialized like this

`var newrequests = $('#newrequests');`

in

`$(function () {});`

Not really sure what is the cause.

I can make it a lot worse by doing this.

```
    newrequests.empty();
    $.each(data, function (i, val) { newrequests.append('<li><a href="/requests/' + val.Ref + '">' + val.Ref + '</a> ' + val.Type + '</li>'); });
```

Comment: The cause of what? You only said you "seem to have a memory leak". What does that mean? What's the actual symptom?

Comment: Meaning that the tab in IE keeps using more and more memory without releasing it.

Comment: Are there performance problems? Is the system under memory pressure? (If there are no performance problems and no memory pressure, releasing memory is pointless.)

Comment: Okay, so you *have* a memory leak. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that it has something to do with the last line of code, that puts the new html inside the ul tag.
Try changing the line into this (old code):

```
document.getElementById('newrequests').innerHTML = h;
```

See also: [jQuery - Internet Explorer memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691080/jquery-internet-explorer-memory-leaks)